# React component failed to compile because 'google' is not defined (google charts)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to use google charts and I keep on getting this error

```
Failed to compile.

src\Map.js
  Line 14:13:  'google' is not defined  no-undef       
  Line 17:13:  'google' is not defined  no-undef       
  Line 25:28:  'google' is not defined  no-undef       
  Line 42:29:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
```

I was following this link here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start. Here is my Map.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Map(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js";
        script.async = true;
        script.setAttribute('id', 'gcs-5645')
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        
        document.getElementById('gcs-5645').addEventListener('load', () => {
            // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        
            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        
            // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
            // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
            // draws it.
            function drawChart() {
        
            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows([
                ['Mushrooms', 3],
                ['Onions', 1],
                ['Olives', 1],
                ['Zucchini', 1],
                ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ]);
        
            // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                            'width':400,
                            'height':300};
        
            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }; 
        }); 

    }, []); 

    return <div></div>; 
}

export default Map;
```

I'm just trying to create a basic pie chart. It is my understanding that I have to wait until the script is loaded, and then the 'google' object will be globally accessible. But then why is it still not defined?

[image]

Am I thinking about this the right way? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think the problem is google is undefined XD

Comment: you need to import the google variable from a library or a file

Comment: So then my question would be, how do I do that?

Comment: I just tested your code. it's working fine. `google` is available globally once `load` event fires

Comment: try to access `google` from `window` object. like `window.google`

Comment: window.google is undefined, and I posted a screenshot of what it's showing me when I refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

**The issue**
if you were trying the dynamically adding `scripts` and adding `onload` listener it was loading the script but the `google` var was binded to window object so if you want to access you would have to use `window.google.<functions>` otherwise the output would be the one you got

**The soulution**
as i had multiple components so i just set it as a `state` probably not a good idea but solves my purpose you can use the `window.google` object directly

### CODE

---

index.html

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="gc" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

</script>
</head>
```

app.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [gc, setGc] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    // this loads google charts
    setGc(window.google);
    console.log("googlecharts", gc);
  }, []);
```

The console output:
[image]